# Wireshark - How to export the info column of all packets to plain text

Tags: wireshark

I have a set of captured packets and I only want the info column of every packet to be exported to plain text, how can I do this?

I am on windows

Answer (score 2):

You can do this through tshark, which is included with wireshark.

1) Add wireshark's install path to your path environment variables (tshark is located in your wireshark directory)

2) Open a command prompt

3) Run -

```
tshark -r file.pcap -T fields -e _ws.col.Info

-r = read file 
-T = output format
-e = specified field
```

You can add additional fields depending on what you plan on doing with the information.  For example:

```
tshark -r file.pcap -T fields -E separator="|" -e http.host -e _ws.col.Info

-E = output format
```

You can also add a filter to only see the packets you're interested in.  Adding to the above example:

```
tshark -r file.pcap -Y "http.request" -T fields -E separator="|" -e http.host -e _ws.col.Info > output.csv

-Y = display filter
> = sends output to a file
```

btw - tshark is awsome for getting what you need w/out having to open the GUI.  See - https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any way to do it directly, but...

You can:

- Export all/selected packets to CSV file.
- Open CSV file in any spreadsheet.
- Copy selected column to text file.